# I can't set size for a computed column

Tags: sql-server

I have a computed column with size = 8000:

```
(json_value([content],'$.UserId'))
```

I am trying to change it to:

```
(CONVERT(varchar(50),json_value([content],'$.UserId')))
```

But I have the followin error:

Error validating the formula for column userId_cp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw0Ck.png)

why?

Comment: Stop using the designers in SSMS. They're full of bugs. The ability to *script* an object into a new query window as an `ALTER` statement is a far better starting point for making changes.

Comment: It doesn't work:

ALTER TABLE Messages
ALTER COLUMN [userId_cp] (CONVERT([varchar](50),json_value([content],'$.UserId'))) PERSISTED;

Comment: You can't `ALTER` a computed column; you must `DROP` and recreate it.